# Get SSH authentication data after key authentication

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, ssh-keys

Is it possible, from the server side to retrieve data used in the key authentication after this is completed? For example, from a pam module, to get the public key used, the challenge used (if it was successful).

Using openssh in Debian 9.

Comment: This would be a serious security hole, if it existed.

Comment: Sorry, I explained myself badly. I edited the question. I mean, getting those information from the server side, like in a pam module called after successful key authentication

Answer (score 0):

You will find interesting the following Stack Exchange article:
[Can I find out which ssh key was used to access an account?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/can-i-find-out-which-ssh-key-was-used-to-access-an-account)

The idea there is to get the information from the logs by setting in
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` the 
value of `LogLevel` to `VERBOSE`.

You might find especially useful the script in the
[answer by F. Hauri](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59943/17660)
where is script is created that is to be added to
`/etc/bash.bashrc` or user's `.bashrc`, that after login from SSH will
create the following environmental variables:

```
set | grep ^SSH
SSH_CLIENT='192.168.1.31 43734 22'
SSH_CONNECTION='192.168.1.31 43734 192.168.1.2 22'
SSH_KEY_USER=user@mydesk
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
```

The script itself is reproduced below, but I recommend reading the original
answer for more information:

```
ssh_oPwd=$OLDPWD
ssh_oUmask=$(umask)
umask 077
ssh_tempdir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/ssh-id-XXXXXXX)
cd $ssh_tempdir || exit 1

ssh_crtFp=$(
    sed -ne "/sshd.\($(($(ps ho ppid $PPID)))\|$PPID\).:.*\(Accepted publickey\|matching .SA key\)/{s/^.* //g;h};\${x;p}" /var/log/sshdusers.log
)
for ((ssh_i=1;ssh_i<=$(wc -l <$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys);ssh_i++));do
    export ssh_line="$(sed -ne ${ssh_i}p <$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys)"
    echo "$ssh_line" >tempKey
    export ssh_lFp=($(ssh-keygen -l -f tempKey))
    if [ "${ssh_lFp[1]}" == "$ssh_crtFp" ] ;then
        export SSH_KEY_USER=${ssh_line##* }
        break
      fi
  done

cd $OLDPWD
OLDPWD=$ssh_oPwd
rm -fR $ssh_tempdir
umask $ssh_oUmask
unset ssh_lFp ssh_line ssh_i ssh_crtFp ssh_tempdir ssh_oUmask ssh_oPwd
```